# How/Where can I find out if i'm forgetting to dispose Redis connections?

Tags: c#, azure, redis

I need to create a tool or some observation mechanism to report me how many redis connections I have going on. We're having problems with this and we're only getting actual data from production environment (azure), and when it's there, it's kinda too-late...

So, in a local machine (where every developer has a redis installed for testing reasons), how can I know how many opened connections I have at a given moment? The ideal number would be zero, cause you open it, get/set whatever, close... right?

Comment: Have a look at this : https://blog.serverdensity.com/monitor-redis/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run [`CLIENT LIST`](https://redis.io/commands/client-list), or [`INFO`](https://redis.io/commands/info) against your Redis instance to find out who's connected at any given moment.

> The ideal number would be zero, cause you open it, get/set whatever, close... right?

Actually, not necessarily - some clients offer the possibility of keeping connections open for pooling purposes.

Comment: is there a more "dynamic" tool? someway to run this at real time?

Comment: You can easily script it and set it up as a cron job. There are also plenty of open source tools as well - Google it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use a class factory to create your redis connections, open them and lease them out to the consumer classes. The consumer classes return them to the factory for reuse or closure.

Comment: I think he wants some kind of monitoring tool.

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio - fair comment - I wonder why he's tagged it with c# ?

Comment: @PhillipH tags can be removed ;)